# Como calcular el siguiente acumulado con mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Observen la tabla que está en la imagen del enlace. Cómo puedo actualizar los acumulados siendo que acumulado es igual al * 0.25 mas el acumulado del periodo anterior? Sé que usando algún ciclo se puede hacer, pero, ¿conoces alguna forma de actualizar la tabla sin recurrir a ellos?
Es decir, un update correcto debería dar como resultado que el acumulado del periodo 1 es igual a 1,2075, el del periodo 2 a 2,3825, el del 3 3,5575 y el del 4 = 4,50675
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es algo así:

```
set @ac=0;
UPDATE notas
  set acumulado=(@ac:=@ac+.25*total);
```

El dataset de partida podría ser este mismo:

```
CREATE TABLE notas(
  matricula_id int,
  asignatura_id int,
  periodo_id int,
  total float,
  acumulado float NOT NULL
  );
INSERT INTO notas (periodo_id,total) VALUES
(1,4.83),
(2,4.7),
(3,4.7),
(4,3.797);
UPDATE notas set matricula_id=576,asignatura_id=515;

+--------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------+
| matricula_id | asignatura_id | periodo_id | total | acumulado |
+--------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------+
|          576 |           515 |          1 |  4.83 |         0 |
|          576 |           515 |          2 |   4.7 |         0 |
|          576 |           515 |          3 |   4.7 |         0 |
|          576 |           515 |          4 | 3.797 |         0 |
+--------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

Con esta consulta podríamos visualizar el acumulado que buscas:

```
set @ac=0;
SELECT *,@ac:=@ac+.25*total FROM notas;
```

El `UPDATE` es para que los datos queden registrados:

```
+--------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------+
| matricula_id | asignatura_id | periodo_id | total | acumulado |
+--------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------+
|          576 |           515 |          1 |  4.83 |    1.2075 |
|          576 |           515 |          2 |   4.7 |    2.3825 |
|          576 |           515 |          3 |   4.7 |    3.5575 |
|          576 |           515 |          4 | 3.797 |   4.50675 |
+--------------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

Como tendrás más asignaturas y alumnos, deberías programarte un bucle que los vaya recorriendo a todos. No olvides de añadir un `WHERE matricula_id=576 AND asignatura_id=515`.

Aunque, mejor todavía, podrías incorporar una puesta a cero del acumulador para cada alumno:

```
UPDATE notas JOIN (
    SELECT matricula_id,asignatura_id,periodo_id,
      if(periodo_id=1,@ac:=0,''),
      @ac:=@ac+.25*total dato
      FROM notas
      ORDER BY 1,2,3
  ) c1 USING(matricula_id,asignatura_id,periodo_id)
  set acumulado=dato;
```

Como ves, son consultas un poco complejas, pero se van desarrollando de forma gradual conforme vas detectando sus limitaciones. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Excelente aporte.

Answer (score 1):

Con MySql 8.0 o superior lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

Utiliznado la función de ventana `SUM()` para calcular el acumulado como `total * 0.25 + acumulado_anterior`.

```
UPDATE notas AS n 
INNER JOIN (SELECT matricula_id, asignatura_id, periodo_id,
                   SUM(total * 0.25) OVER (PARTITION BY matricula_id, asignatura_id ORDER BY periodo_id ASC) AS acumulado
            FROM notas) sq USING (matricula_id, asignatura_id, periodo_id)
SET n.acumulado = sq.acumulado;
```

En este caso como especifiqué `PARTITION BY matricula_id, asignatura_id` cada vez que cambie la matricula o la asignatura el acumulado comienza desde cero.

Comment: Buen aporte el `OVER` y el `PARTITION BY`, habrá que ir actualizándose...

Comment: Muchas gracias, probé con el over... pero no me funcionó creo que por no tener instalado MySQL 8.0

Comment: De nada @DanielAlvarez!!! Solo funciona a partir de la versión 8.0 de MySql, no sabía que versión estabas utilizando.

Comment: Gracias @DavidJP!!! MySql a evoluciona mucho a partir de la versión 8.0, y se simplifican mucho algunas queries.

Answer (score 1):

Logré tener el mismo resultado con esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
matricula_id,   asignatura_id, periodo_id AS per, total,
    (   SELECT SUM(total * .25) AS acum
        FROM notas
        WHERE matricula_id = 576 
        AND asignatura_id = 515
        AND  periodo_id <= per
    ) as acumulado
FROM 
    notas
WHERE 
    matricula_id = 576 
    AND asignatura_id = 515;
```

Había optado por un replace into notas... select...

Pero tu consulta para actualizar me funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias bro!

Comment: Buena idea para no utilizar variables...